# rails4 error on association build or create when using before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

i have this assocaition:

```
has_many :exam_portions, -> { order :position }
belongs_to :exam
```

in exam_portion there are before_save callback:

```
before_create :proper_position

private

def proper_position
  self.position = exam.exam_portions.count
end
```

when try to build association following error are raised from before_save callback:
  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'exam_portions' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your exam_portion does not have an exam during its creation.

If you create it this way it should work:

```
exam.exam_portions.create()
```

To ensure your exam_portion have an exam you should add a validate_presence on exam.

**EDIT**

Here is what we have figured out with Georgi:

```
exam = Gaku::Exam.where(:name => "Final", :use_weighting => true, :weight => 6).first_or_create 
# Does not work
exam_portion = exam.exam_portions.build(:name => 'Ruby 101', :max_score => 200).save
# Works
exam_portion = exam.exam_portions.create(:name => 'Ruby 101', :max_score => 200)
```

Maybe it's a bug in Rails 4.

Comment: this code was working on rails3 but in rails4 not. I tried with create and build no success. Same error.  `exam = Gaku::Exam.where(:name => "Final", :use_weighting => true, :weight => 6).first_or_create
  exam_portion = exam.exam_portions.build(:name => 'Ruby 101', :max_score => 200).save`
`

Comment: Did you check that the exam record has been persisted ?

Comment: yes it is persisted. `exam.persisted?
=> true` Interesting is that when build association exam_id in exam_portion object is 0

Comment: That's interesting. But have you tried to do it this way? exam.exam_portions.create(:name => 'Ruby 101', :max_score => 200)

Comment: intersting with .create work and position is correct and before_save callback work . With where(:name => 'Ruby 101', :max_score => 200).first_or_create didnt.

Comment: Maybe build is bugged in Rails 4, because it should build the inverse association.

Comment: i will try digging more. i hope all is fixed in final 4 version

Comment: Okay, meanwhile I edited my post with the solution. If you find any other solutions I would be happy to know them.